# Enable ABP application service to consume xml

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

We have a scenario with a specific vendor integration. The data flow is that they will send us a notification of an event that has occurred within their system.

The notification from their system is an HTTP **POST** where the **Content-Type** request header is set to **application/xml** and the body contains a specific **XML** message.

In a plain ASP.NET Core API project, you just have to add XML serializer formatter like below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
}
```

But we can't seem to find a configuration option for the ABP the framework. We got this to work in ABP version 1.1.2 by just calling the `.AddMvc.AddXmlSerliazerFormatters()` again during configuration but this is not ideal, but allow the applications service to bind based on the content-type header.

We are the process of upgrading to the latest version of ABP 2.6.2 but this is the one functionality that we now can get to work at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.